# Engine Oil leaking near dipstick

Tags: engine, honda, oil-leak, odyssey

Attached is picture of under the hood of 2016 Honday odyssey.

My Mechanic replaced the bad alternator, and when he was testing the car he noticed oil leaking from the area in the picture, near dip stick.

After alternator replacement, car starts and runs, but there is now engine check light.

OBD scan code is P3497.

Google search shows several root causes, one of them is low engine oil level/pressure. May be that explains it, but just need expert opinion from someone.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Does the dipstick indicate that there is the correct amount of oil in the engine?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Was the CEL indicated when you took it into the mechanic ... or did it appear after you got it back?

Answer (score 1):

The OBD code P3497 on a Honda Odyssey relates to the VPS (Valve Pause System) for cylinder deactivation when full engine power is not needed.  P3497 is for bank 2. P3400 is for bank 1. The most likely cause for this code is a faulty rocker arm oil pressure switch. There are other possibilities as well, but less likely which include faulty wiring or low oil pressure to bank 2. I would start with testing the Bank 2 switch to validate the resistance is within spec. If it is not within spec replace it.

Comment: It could possibly be caused by the wrong weight oil.